General purpose root function for real number results
Been trying to implement a simple root function, that given a numbers n and k will return the kth root of the number.
Initially started with the following:
double myroot(doubl n, double k)
{
  return std::pow(n, 1.0 / k);
}

However there are many cases where this fails, such as:
myroot(-125,3)     // nan - should be -5
myroot(-125,3.001) // nan - should be: -4.9973192...

The C++ standard specifies the result of pow as being nan when "if n is finite and negative and k is finite and non-integer."
I then started adding code to handle edge cases, but it got pretty complex very quickly.

Q: Looking for a generally applicable root function that will provide results when it can in the real domain otherwise to return nan.

"Presumably this is the same in other languages." - Why would you assume that? All languages are different and you can never make assumptions about such things across different languages.

Please don't tag unrelated languages.

−4.9973192 is not a solution for (−125)^(1/3.001). (−4.9973192)^3.001 is about −124.99938315 − 0.392698435 i. That is a non-trivial imaginary part. There is no real solution. −4.9973192 is a solution for −(125^(1/3.001)), and that is not any root of −125. So, just to start, you will have to define what function you are actually trying to calculate. If, as your examples suggest, you want n^(1/k) for positive n and −((−n)^(1/k)) for negative n, then all you have to do is test n and calculate either pow(n, 1./k) or -pow(-n, 1./k).

Note that 1/3 can't be represented by floating point numbers since it's a periodic number in binary (just like it is in decimal).  You are actually doing pow(-125.0, 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125). That doesn't have a real solution either. That's going to be the case for effectively all non-integer exponents. That's probably why it's defined to return NaN for all of them (when x is negative).

check the documentation: If base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer, a domain error occurs and a range error may occur.

You have to do it in complex domain. You can convert the numbers to complex numbers and do std::pow on that, but that will only give you one root. (For example, the equation x³=-1 has three roots), and to find "the real number" root from the root returned by complex std::complex requires  a non-trivial algorithm that accounts for the floating point errors mentioned in other comments. On the other hand, I highly doubt -std::pow(-x, y) for negative x is what you want, because it would just return -5 for x=-25, y=0.5.

@WeijunZhou the question is asking for roots in the real domain; not all complex numbers are in the real domain.

@KeeganFisher If you have to do it absolutely in the real domain, you need to convert the exponential to a fractional number, taking into floating point errors, which is not well-defined and not even possible. A negative number raised to an irrational power always give a number with non-zero imaginary part. Are you familiar with how the function xʸ is defined mathematically? When I said "you have to do it in the complex domain", it's based on mathematics.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/317546/511751. You at least have to clarify which operator you are talking about, and if you really mean the discrete real operator, it cannot be done because it's extremely sensitive to floating point errors. Most of the comments above assumes the complex operator, which is also the most natural choice mathematically.

I wouldn't try to write such a mysqrt() function at all.   Apart from the "edge cases", there are also cases for which there is no solution (e.g. there is no real value which can be raised to an even power (2, 4, 6, etc) which gives -1 - all the roots are either purely imaginary or complex [in the sense of having both real and imaginary parts non-zero]).   Most calculations that need a root of a value (real or complex) have some constraints (e.g.  not the whole domain of real numbers for both n and k) which makes the number of possible "edge cases" tractable.

@Peter for situations where there are not solution in the Real domain I'm happy for it to return nan, as i'd be using double/float and not complex types as denoted in the question.

@phuclv I literally referenced the exact sentence in the question, please read my question.

Re “for situations where there are not solution in the Real domain I'm happy for it to return nan”: This conflicts with your example for myroot(-125, 3.001). That has no real solution, but you say you want −4.9973192. To fix the question, you must resolve this contradiction.

You can simply use the absolute value of n, then change the sign of the answer based on the original input n, so long as the input k is both odd and an integer, otherwise you can run the original std::pow() function, which will return -NaN for specific scenarios (i.e. k is not an integer = -NaN, n is negative && k is even == -NaN).
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

double myroot(double n, double k)
{
    bool isNegativeN = n < 0;
    bool isIntK = ((int) k) == k;
    bool isOddK = isIntK && (int) k % 2 == 1;
        
    return isNegativeN && isIntK && isOddK ? 
        std::pow(abs(n), 1.0 / k) * -1 : 
        std::pow(n, 1.0 / k);
}

int main() {
     std::cout << myroot(-1,2) << '\n'; // -nan
     std::cout << myroot(-125,3.001) << '\n'; // -nan
     std::cout << myroot(-125,3); // -5
}


n=-1 and k=2? This produces real roots when there aren’t any.

@lastchance you're right. check the edit for edge cases. I was originally just trying to make the function match his desired output (i.e. "myroot(-125,3.001) // nan - should be: -4.9973192...")

any reason for a downvote? I'm asking because I'd like to know if it was for breaking some standard at StackOverflow, as I'm pretty new here.

I didn't downvote but I believe the downvote is because the answer is wrong or not helpful, instead of violating some SO rules. Checking k for even integer does not really help much. You also have to check for all rational numbers whose numerator is an even number, and then it becomes a mess due to floating point errors. It's basically unfixable.

@Keegan I didn't downvote, as I don't have enough points but wouldn't have in any case because you made a good attempt and though you fixed one issue, there's still some others.

@WeijunZhou I assume you closed the question, but if you had read my question you'd realise, I went down the same path as Keegan, I came up with a solution then as stated found more and more edge cases that needed handling, just like you mentioned, hence I came to SO to see if others had encountered a similar issue and if so what their solutions were.

@AlwaysBecurious You don't need to assume. You can check the timeline to see who closed it. I'm one of them, but I cannot single-handedly close it and two other users find your question unclear. You need to clarify what the expected behavior is when it comes to floating point errors in the exponent (note the comment by ikegami). Once we have a clear specification, the question can be reopened and we can discuss the feasible approach to solve your problem.

@WeijunZhou Literally the last line of the question clearly states the requirement. Which is simply: if the solution is in the real domain to have a result in terms of the type otherwise for all other solutions including ones that require complex solution to return NaN.  tbh I'm not sure if you're trolling or if you genuinely just didn't read the whole question and simply decided to vote down and close. Keegan answered the same question you posed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79225121/general-purpose-root-function-for-real-number-results/79225186?noredirect=1#comment139710107_79225121

@AlwaysBecurious Let me repeat: I didn't downvote. I am not trolling. I have read your question carefully before even writing the first comment. Do you understand how unstable it can be with respect to floating point error? If you don't, you won't understand what I'm talking about. Try some simple cases with WolframAlpha that you think you know the answer, perturb the expoenent by 1e-7, and you can see what I mean. The problem is that whether your function should return NaN or not is extremely sensitive to small perturbations in the exponent.

@Keegan Fisher, I didn't vote either way on either your or the original post or play any role in thread closure. The task would be better defined if the function signature was double myroot(double n, int k), since the oddness or evenness of k would make more sense for an int and the sensitivity to the exponent wouldn't come into play. Otherwise, the task is better performed in complex space.
